# QTextEdit auto text finisher

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any QT class for creation text finisher (If I type "hel", it will automatically finished word with "lo")? Sorry for bad terminology, I don't know how to describe it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is QCompleter but that works an QLineEdit and QComboBox by default only. I never used it but I suppose it should be possible to attach it to a customized QTextEdit too.

Maybe google with QCompleter and QTextEdit as keywords.

Comment: It's indeed possible To use `QCompleter` with `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit` (or with anything really). It's a bit more work, you need to trigger completion (usually from overriden `keyEvent` method) and provide the initial text for completion. I think there is an example showing how to do this in SDK, and docs of `QCompleter` and/or text editor widgets should cover this too.